# Let $f: [0, +\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such as f' is decreasing and positive. Prove that $\sum_ {n=1}^\infty f'(n) $ converges iff f is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

It seems a lot like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571660/if-f-is-positive-decreasing-and-continuous-on-0-infty-show-that-int), but I wasn't able to prove with the same tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f'$ is decreasing, we have
$$f(n)-f(n-1)=\int_{n-1}^nf'(x)\,\mathrm dx \ge \int_{n-1}^nf'(n)\,\mathrm dx=f'(n).$$
Similarly,
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=\int_{n}^{n+1}f'(x)\,\mathrm dx \le \int_{n}^{n+1}f'(n)\,\mathrm dx=f'(n).$$
By adding these inequalities for $n=1,2,\ldots, N$, we get
$$ f(N+1)-f(1)\le \sum_{n=1}^Nf'(n)\le f(N)-f(0).$$
Conclude.